# Typedef C++, couldn't resolve its meaning

Tags: c++, typedef

I read this typedef line in a C++ book, but I couldn't resolve its meaning:

```
typedef Shape* (*CreateShapeCallBack)();
```

Now, CreateShapeCallBack stands for what, any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the type of a pointer to a function that returns a pointer to a Shape and takes no parameters. You could use it like this:

```
Shape * Func() {
   // do stuff - return Shape pointer
}

...
CreateShapeCallBack p = Func;
```

Answer (score 2):

Pointer to a function returning a pointer to a `Shape` instance (which is `Shape*`) and taking `void` as a param - no params.

Compare this with, for example `typedef int (*function_pointer)(double);` - this is a pointer to a function that takes `double` as a parameter and returns `int`...

Answer (score 1):

It defines CreateCallBack as a function pointer.
The function haves no arguments and returns the Shape pointer.

Answer (score 1):

```
returntype (*functionpointer)(parameters, ...)
```

is a function pointer in c++